# p,m and b columns in tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, columns

I wonder why p columns are aligned at the bottom and b columns aligned at the top?
[image]

created with this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|m{0.3\linewidth}|b{0.3\linewidth}|}
\hline
\centering header p &
\centering header m &   
\centering header b \tabularnewline
\hline
text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
text which is considerably longer than the width of the column  & 
text which is considerably longer than the width of the column 
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33257/how-to-vertically-and-horizontally-centre-text-and-images-in-different-table-c It *is* the expected result.

Comment: People finding this question might also be looking for [tables - Definition/explantion of tabular column types - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99094/definition-explantion-of-tabular-column-types)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

- `p` means normal cells, they are like parbox with alignment at the top line
- `b` means alignment at the bottom, so the baseline is at the bottom line
- `m` means alignment in the vertical center, i.e. the baseline is in the center.

So the position for alignment is meant. In your picture, the top line of the first text, the middle of the second and the bottom line of the last text are all in a line:

[image: table cell alignment]

Comment: Ok, I understand. My problem was that it is counter-intuitive.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no (simple) way to have a column aligned at the bottom when the other columns are specified with `r`, `l` and `c`? In a table `\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}b{1cm}rlc}` the three last columns are aligned at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

For some users who are familiar with word processors, these `p` and `b` columns in LaTeX tables are counter-intuitive. With `tblr` environment of LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), there are another two column types `h` and `f`, which will align cell text at row head and row foot, respectively:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{h{4em}t{4em}m{4em}b{4em}f{4em}}
\hline
{row\\head} & {top\\line} & {middle} & {line\\bottom} & {row\\foot} \\
\hline
{row\\head} & {top\\line} & {11\\22\\mid\\44\\55} & {line\\bottom} & {row\\foot} \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do h and b actually work or mean? Thankfully, you showed how they affect the alignment, but I still don't quite understand their actual meaning to link with their effects.

Comment: h means put text in the head of the cell, f means put text in the foot of the cell.

Comment: And what about the meaning of b and t? Is there a visual explanation of how they place the text?

Comment: b means put bottom line in the middle, t means put top line in the middle.