# Definition/explantion of tabular column types

Tags: tables, columns

In a question I recently asked ([How to make table with rotated table headers in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98388/how-to-make-table-with-rotated-table-headers-in-latex)) the accepted answer used some features of tabular column types that I was not familiar with, e.g.,

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} cl*{10}c @{}}
```

I tried Googling for `latex "@{}"` but that just brought up some generic LaTeX pages.

Where can I got to learn about `@{}` tabular columns and other options?

---

Okay, so I found the answer in appendix C.10 of Lamport's book, but I'd like to know where to look for electronic resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array package documentation (`texdoc array` on some systems) documents the original array column types as well as the additional ones added by that package. See table 1 on page 2.

Comment: That table is great. Easily found, near the beginning of the file.