# cannot align text in a simple table

Tags: tables, color

I can not simply align the text by using `p{xx\linewidth}` and `\color` in the same tabular.

The result is very awful... a conflicting package problem ?

anyone who has an idea is welcome ;)

sample:

[image: why B below A and C ?]

source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage{color}            


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}}

A &   \color{red}{B}   &  C \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\textcolor{red}{B}` or `\leavevmode\color{red}{B}`.  The problem is in invoking `\color` while in vertical mode.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Maybe you should post it as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke a `p` column, you are in a `\parbox` (or is it `minipage`?) that enters that column in vertical mode.  Some commands act differently in vertical (page) mode than in horizontal (paragraph) mode.  `\color` is one of them.  The way to remedy the issue is to either use `\textcolor` which will leave vertical mode itself, or to explicitly leave vertical mode with a `\leavevmode`.  I show both methods below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage{color}            


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}}

A &   \leavevmode\color{red}B   &  C \\

A &   \textcolor{red}{B}   &  C \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other macros that will suffer the same fate, and thus require a `\leavevmode` to behave in the "expected" way, include `\llap`, `\rlap`, and (outside of `tabular` environments) `\marginpar`.

Comment: @Jc Crivello I had the same thought, and found [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35293/p-m-and-b-columns-in-tables) that may be helpful.

Comment: @sk8forether Vertical alignment of the `\parbox` is certainly an issue too, but it is unique from the vertical/horizontal mode issue in which you found yourself with this question.

Comment: @JcCrivello Note that `\color{red}{B}` of your MWE, while not wrong, gives an improper impression. `\color{}` is a declaration, taking no additional arguments such as `{B}`.  All text that follows is affected by the color change until the end of the current group.  Thus, the syntax should be `\color{} B`.  On the other hand `\textcolor{}{}` is the macro that not only defines the color, but also the text to which to apply it.