# Centering cells of a tabular column using m{}

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want to use a tabular to list some headlines, that might be quite long or contain linebreaks. The first column is kind of an Index or Key for the second columns content, so i would like to (vertically) center it (and i'll add `\midrule`s for readability). To achieve the centering i included the `array`-package with its column definition `m{2.5em}`. The remaining two columns have fixed widths, too. But - as in the following MWE - the first column is somehow vertically placed top or bottom but not centered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,div=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}m{2.5em}b{.5\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-8em}p{5.5em}}%
    \toprule\textbf{\#}&\textbf{Name}&\textbf{Notes}\\\midrule%
    A & 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit&\\
    B & \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-8em}
        An\\even\\higher\\row\\with\\linebreaks
    \end{minipage}&\\
    2 & Short Entry & 
    \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And here's how it looks, as you can see, the first column is not vertically centered (i know in this quick MWE the minipage does not have enough space below).
[image: MWE of the non vertically centered first column]

Any ideas?

Comment: possibly similar to [this question about tables with multiple lines in some cells](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells); an answer i just posted there addresses much the same situation.  although it doesn't use `m{}` or `booktabs`, it does address vertical centering, and top and bottom clearance with `array`.

Comment: You might look at [this answers about differently vertically aligned cells](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33327/4427)

Comment: @barbarabeeton i didn't get your example to work, but i think it is also a little bit too static in it's use of heights.

Comment: @egreg thanks fot the hint, i haven't understood the finalcell-command yet, but i was able to adapt it to my situation (well removing one argument...) and it works. After i had applied it to my first cell (of the 2nd column) even the B got centered. So it seems, the reason for the broken m-definition of the first column is occurs, if the second column produces an automomatic linebreak. Thanks for the hint, could you post that as an answer?

Comment: It may be a bug in the `array` package. If I change the `b` placement to `m`, both the _A_ and the _B_ are aligned to the centre.

Comment: Oh, you're right, that's a nice observation. And if you change the `b`of the second column to `p`, both the _A_ and the _B_ geht vertically aligned to the top.

Comment: @Ronny Why don't you post your solution as a self-answer? Or, if it's still not satisfying, add it to your question, stating what's needed.

Comment: @egreg Oh, i wasn't sure, whether self-answers are that appropriate. I'll work on a solution (to the MWE), based on your suggestion, this evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one solution mentioned by egreg in the comments to the original question was, to encapsulate the content and calculate the height to be used to a minipage. I adapted that to my MWE and that would look like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,div=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,calc}

\newcommand{\finalcell}[1]{%
    \begingroup\sbox0{\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-8em}%
            \raggedright#1\end{minipage}}%
        \xdef\finalheight{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0+\smallskipamount\relax}%
    \endgroup
    \vspace{.5\cmidrulesep}
    \begin{minipage}[t][\finalheight][t]{.5\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-8em}\raggedright#1\end{minipage}%&
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}m{2.5em}m{.5\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-8em}m{5.5em}}%
    \toprule\textbf{\#}&\textbf{Name}&\textbf{Notes}\\\midrule%
    A & \finalcell{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit}&\\\addlinespace[3\cmidrulesep]
    B & \finalcell{An\\even\\higher\\row\\with\\linebreaks}&\\\addlinespace[3\cmidrulesep]
    2 & \finalcell{Short Entry} & 
    \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which would look like this.

[image: MWE of the now vertically centered first column]

I additionally added `\addlinespace`s to the end of the lines, which could be optimized - i think - by increasing the linespace of the booktabs tabular in general before starting the tabular.

Comment: Yes, it might actually be a bug in the `array`package, concerning line breaks in m-columns.

Answer (score 5):

use `tabularx` with a redefinition of the `X` columntype, then you do not need the `calc` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,div=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft}m{2.5em} X m{5.5em}}%
    \toprule\textbf{\#}&\textbf{Name}&\textbf{Notes}\\\midrule%
    A & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit&\\
    B & An\newline even\newline higher\newline 
        row\newline with\newline linebreaks &         \\
    2 & Short Entry & 
    \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but the text still looks like separate entries or items, not like text.  the baselines are too far apart and too even, so it's not so easy to distinguish where A ends and B begins.  and the uneven horizontal spacing in A makes it hard to read; ragged right is your friend here.

Comment: I know, but that was not the problem of the original question ...

Comment: Herbert your solution also works fine, though there are two drawbacks (and yes they are not mentioned in the first entry). First is, that the second column will be a parameter that i want to encapsulate either way (for example because i don't want to replace all `\\` by ` \newlines` before i insert that). Secondly - in my original code the table gets quite long, so i use `longtable`; getting `longtable` and `tabularx`to work together is - in my oppinion - quite a challenge.

Comment: Then use a minipage, where is the problem? And with package `ltablex` the `tabularx` environment can have a pagebreak

Comment: The first point is indeed solved by a minipage. For the second one: I like the way longtable defines firsthead/lastfoot and so on. but as you can see, my solution does work without tabularX (okay well - it does just because i calculate the width of the middle column myself instead of specifying a tabular width). But i might also check the `ltablex`-package - thanks for the idea.

Comment: With `ltablex` it _is_ a longtable with all that possibilities of  head and foot definitions

Answer (score 3):

applying the method used in [an answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells) to the original example, here is an approach that gives an improved result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,div=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,calc}
\newdimen{\lcellwd}
\newcommand{\lcell}[2][\lcellwd]{%
  $\vcenter{\hsize#1\baselineskip11pt\vspace*{3pt}\raggedright#2\strut\par}$}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\lcellwd}{.5\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-8em}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}m{2.5em}b{.5\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-8em}p{5.5em}}%
    \toprule\textbf{\#}&\textbf{Name}&\textbf{Notes}\\\midrule%
    A & 
    \lcell{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit}&\\
    B & \lcell{%
        An\\even\\higher\\row\\with\\linebreaks}&\\
    2 & Short Entry\strut & 
    \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** by moving the `\baselineskip` instruction to just before `\par` in the definition of `\lcell` it is possible to introduce a variable that can be set externally:

```
\newlength{\lcbaseline}
\setlength{\lcbaseline}{11pt}
\newcommand{\lcell}[2][\lcellwd]{%
  $\vcenter{\hsize#1\vspace*{3pt}\raggedright#2\strut\baselineskip\lcbaseline\par}$}
```

this will adjust the baselines of continuous text, as in group "A", since the baselines currently in force are used when a paragraph is "wrapped".  however, it breaks down when `\\` is used, and i haven't figured out where `\\` "freezes" the current baseline value.  using `\break` instead of `\\` does produce the adjusted baselines, but it isn't very latexy; including the `\baselineskip` instruction in two places would overcome that problem, but it's inelegant.

Comment: Your solution definetly works, but the thing i noticed is, that the 2 is - just a little bit - too low. And the one thing i don't understand is: I thought your solution is quite static (and fixed to one font size) due to the 11pt and 3pt spaces you insert. But it isn't. That's fascinating, can you explain, why you choose these values?

Comment: @Ronny -- the 2 is lower than the "name" entry because of the `\strut`.  i added the strut to make sure there would be uniform visual clearance above and below entries in the "name" column.  but the 2 has no descender; adding a strut there would ensure the same baseline.  as for the spacing values i chose, they are based on experimentation with different sized text, at 9-11pt.  (i also defined a `\slcell` for 8pt or smaller text, with `\baselineskip 9.5pt`.)  when they all looked acceptable to me, i "froze" the values.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I tried your solution for 14pt (just out of curiosity) and it looked not that nice to me. But it may depend on personal preferences, which way to go; i prefer a more general way using e.g. the way i presented and setting spaces to more general values (as `\cmidrulespace` font booktabs). And my solution does not need the `\strut` to align the first column.

Comment: @Ronny -- 14pt type will certainly need a larger baseline than 11pt.  i have some ideas for making that part of the definition more flexible, and will report what i find.